# How to deal with the Downloading maven dependencies. using netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I am creating a maven project using netbeans but my Dependencies could not be downloaded and keep getting the following error. I have allowed Netbeans in my firewall.

> Failed to execute goal on project GrossDP: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.example:GrossDP:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed
>   to collect dependencies at
>   org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0: Could
>   not transfer artifact org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:pom:2.2.0
>   from/to eclipselink
>   (http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo):
>   Connect to ftp.ing.umu.se:80 [ftp.ing.umu.se/130.239.117.84] failed:
>   Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: I cannot even connect to the given URL via browser, so this seems not to be a firewall or Maven issue. Any reason why you are using this particular repository?

Comment: @JoachimRohde Thanks for the tip up. Netbeans had generated the URL but its actually not working. I change the URL to http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo and now it seems to work. All the Dependancies have been found.